# how to make my website contact form to multiple recipients (emails)

Tags: php, html

how can i make my web contact form send request to multiple emails and each emails will not see the others receives email that receives the same request from the web contact form. My code is working fine but just only sending the request from the contact form to only one email address, how can i send it to multiple emails this is my code below :

```
    <?php
     $name = $_POST['name']; // form field
     $email = $_POST['email']; // form field
     $message = $_POST['message']; // form field

     if ($_POST['submit']){
     $from = "Contact us<info@xxxxxx>"; //enter your email address
     $to = "xxxxxx@outlook.com"; //enter the email address of the contact your sending to
     $subject = "you have 6 pending mail"; // subject of your email
     $bcc = "";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, 'headers' => $headers);

    $text = ''; // text versions of email.
    $html = "<html><body>

    Name: $name <br> Email: $email <br>Message: $message <br>

    </body></html>"; // html versions of email.

    $crlf = "\n";

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    //do not ever try to call these lines in reverse order
    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

     $host = "localhost"; // all scripts must use localhost
     $username = "xxxxxxx"; //  your email address (same as webmail username)
     $password = "xxxxxx"; // your password (same as webmail password)

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    }
    else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    // header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
    }
      }
     ?>

     <form action="qservers_mail.php" method="post">
    <table border="0" style="background:#ececec" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="left"><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>Email address</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="email"></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td valign="top">Comments</td><td><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write them separated by commas.

`$to = "first@mail.ru, second@mail.ru";`

Comment: try it but is still show the emails of others that received it too